# Firefox sometimes ignores JPEG files with .jpg and .jpeg extensions on file input

Tags: html, firefox, windows-10

When there's a file input control to upload pictures that accepts JPEG files:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```

… my copy of Firefox will only allow JPEG files with ".jfif" extension:

[image: Select file dialog]

It only happens in my PC (other coworkers get "*.jpg; *.jpeg"), it only happens in Firefox (Chrome and Edge implement their own extension list) and it didn't happen a while ago.

What does this behaviour depend on? Is this a common issue that I should address in my upload markup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even in 62.0.3 the bug is still reproducable for me - But the bug is known and already listed at bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1367490

This workaround works for me:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jfif, .jpeg, .jpg">
```

Comment: I've checked some more PCs running Windows 10 and I can confirm this is totally broken in Firefox. Your workaround is a must if you need to support this browser.

Comment: The bug has been fixed. It should be available when Firefox 78 is released.